# Gnome-terminal --tab variables don't work

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I am trying to open a new terminal tab and have a for loop print the iterator.

`gnome-terminal --tab -- /bin/bash -c "for (( num=1;num!=-1;num++ ));do echo $num; sleep 2;done"`

After executing the above command for some reason it only prints out the number `3`

[image]

However, if i run it the command without using gnome-terminal it works as expected.
`for (( num=1;num!=-1;num++ ));do echo $num; sleep 2;done`

[image]

Anyone know why?

Comment: Please replace images with its text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$num` will interpolate the value of `num` in the original shell into the string passed as argument to the new `/bin/bash`.

Use `'` instead of `"` to suppress interpolation.